# Mini "Xinda" board with 3 pins

Tags: sensors

Does anybody know what is this board, if it has some resistors and how is it wired to the sensor.

The component on it is Dallas 18B20 digital temperature sensor.

[image: Link to photos: https://imgur.com/a/yqFWJ]

[image]

Comment: "Guessing games" aren't a good fit for Super User because they generally aren't useful to others.  Even if this question was about a common computer part (which it isn't), you need the picture to know what the question relates to.  So even if someone else had the same question, they would have no way to find your question or any answers.

Comment: @fixer1234 This is a not-uncommon part used in maker equipment. For me, something almost identical came as part of a sensor kit. The problem is that there is almost no n00b documentation on how these work, at least not as easily searchable from the sensor part number or the markings on the board. It took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: @ArenCambre: It's great that you were able to provide an answer.  The issue I raised is one that's been discussed a bit on Meta.  Suppose I have the same part and also wonder what it is.  If SU had the equivalent of Google Image Search or TinEye, and images in previous questions and answers were indexed, I could look for previous answers to my own question.  Lacking that, there's no practical way for any previous Q&A to help me.  So the usefulness of these kinds of questions is limited to the OP, which defeats the purpose of a knowledge base for future, similar questions.

Comment: I found this using a Google search. :-)

Comment: @ArenCambre: Surprisingly, these images are now indexed on Google and I was able to find this question by doing a image search on one of these images.  However, if I had my own mystery part, took a picture of it, and tried to find an answer via an image search, the odds of a match are pretty low.

Comment: I found this as the 2nd search result on a Google search for **xinda board**. In that respect, a text search worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same struggle with an identical sensor from RobotLinking. I discovered that the **-** next to the left pin is for the ground, the middle pin is for the 3.3V or 5V (this sensor apparently can do either), and the right pin, marked **S**, is for the sensor's output. I have a sensor set with 37 sensors, most of which are like this.

As for what this board does, from the best I can tell:

- It's a temperature sensor
- It has an integrated LED to show when you are reading the temperature
- It has a resistor built into it, so no need to use a resistor to protect your controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I've been pulling my hair trying to figure this out!